# fuzzywuzzy package logic in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve following problem using fuzzywuzzy package in python.

**Problem:**

I have an excel file which has four columns, I want to compare first column with remaining three columns, where ever there is a fuzzy match, i want to assign a score. so, in total there will be three scores, in the end i want to see only the highest score column in the output.

**Input:**

haritha      harithainc    harith

following is the code i have used.

```
for index,row in data.iterrows():
data['flag1'] = fuzz.ratio(data['centre'],data['org'])
```

but this is not iterating through rows.

Is fuzz.ratio correct approach to follow to do fuzzy matching that we do in excel.

Thanks a lot in advance.

I changed code as below.

```
for index,row in data.iterrows(): 
   data['flag1'] = fuzz.ratio(str(row['centre']),str(row['org']))
```

but still its giving same number across all rows

Comment: You have Indent Error! You don't use anything `index, row` from the `loop`!

Comment: Hey Thanks for the input, could you please tell me how to solve this??

Comment: I changed code as below.                                                                                                     
           for index,row in data.iterrows():
   data['flag1'] = fuzz.ratio(str(row['centre']),str(row['org'])),  but still its giving same number across all rows

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the how you initialize `data`and the `type`ofc`data`.